# itertools.groupby() values disappear

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-science

I have a nested list `[['A','B'],['A','C'],['D'],['C','A']]`

```
import itertools
d = {}
for key, group in itertools.groupby([['A','B'],['A','C'],['D'],['C','A']], lambda x: x[0]):
    d[key] = list(group)
print(d)
```

Now I will have `{'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': [['D']], 'C': [['C', 'A']]}`

However, since 'D' is the only nested list with a single element, I want all single-element to print out as a number `0`.

I want to output: `{'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': [['C', 'A']]}`, so I added an if-else clause and changed my code to:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby([['A','B'],['A','C'],['D'],['C','A']], lambda x: x[0]):
    if len(list(group)[0]) > 1:
        d[key] = list(group)
    else: d[key] = 0
print(d)
```

However, the above code printed out as `{'A': [], 'D': 0, 'C': []}`. I didn't see anything wrong with my code. However, why do `A` and `C` print out an empty list?

Comment: Your first `list` exhausts the generator. you need assign to a temp variable.

Comment: i.e. put `group = list(group)` in the loop, then just use `group` in the `if` block.

Comment: Thank you! Creating a new variable works, but I still don't quite understand why it doesn't work if I don't create a new variable...

Comment: Because `group` is not a list; it's an iterator that can only be used once.

Comment: but if I can only use it once, at least it should print out: {'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': []}, I mean 'A' should have its elements. Why it print out all [] empty lists for both A and C? Where did I use the generator the first time?

Comment: @TroyBear *Where did I use the generator the first time?* When you call `len(list(group)[0])`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing is the first call of `list(group)` inside of the call to `len` exhausts the iterator that `group` points to; you can only use it once. You therefor need to save the values in a temp list.

You can do:

```
import itertools 

d = {}
li=[['A','B'],['A','C'],['D'],['C','A']]

for key, group in itertools.groupby(li, lambda x: x[0]):
    gv=list(group)
    if len(gv) > 1:
        d[key] = gv
    else: d[key] = 0
    
print(d)
# {'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': 0}
```

You can also shorten a bit with:

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(li, lambda x: x[0]):
    gv=list(group)
    d[key]=gv if len(gv) > 1 else 0
```

---

You asked *Where did I use the generator the first time?*

Consider the following example:

```
>>> gen=(x*2 for x in (1,2,3))  # a generator expression
>>> type(gen)
<class 'generator'>
>>> list(gen)
[2, 4, 6]
>>> list(gen)
[]
```

If you use `list` on a generator, that exhausts the generator. You used `list(group)` inside of `len` which exhausts the generator. With your second call to `list` -- there is nothing left.

Comment: but if I can only use it once, at least it should print out: {'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': []}, I mean 'A' should have its elements. Why it print out all [] empty lists for both A and C? Where did I use the generator the first time?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that when you call `list(group)` you are forcing the generator to generate all elements, so next time you use it it has no elements on it.

Use the following:

```py
import itertools

d = {}

for key, group in itertools.groupby([['A','B'],['A','C'],['D'],['C','A']], lambda x: x[0]):
    group_list = list(group)
    d[key] = group_list if len(group_list[0]) > 1 else 0
print(d)
```

**Output**

```py
{'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': [['C', 'A']]}
```

Comment: but if I can only use it once, at least it should print out: {'A': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C']], 'D': 0, 'C': []}, I mean 'A' should have its elements. Why it print out all [] empty lists for both A and C? Where did I use the generator the first time?

Comment: @TroyBear, I am not sure what you are asking. When you convert a generator into a list the generator has no more elements to use. Try the following if this helps to understand: `>>> generator = (1 for _ in range(5))` then, `>>> list(generator)` and then again `>>> list(generator)`. The first time you call `list(generator)` you will get a list of all elements, but the generator will no longer have elements, so next time you will get an empty list.